# php insert into database function then select all in another function error

Tags: php, sql, pdo

I am running a php script which will insert a new record into a database within a function and after it has been inserted I wanted to get all contents from the same database using a second function but I get the following error

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function prepare() on
>   null in /www1/fe5/www.seansdesigns.co.uk/web/foodApp/test.php:33 Stack
>   trace: #0 /www1/fe5/www.seansdesigns.co.uk/web/foodApp/test.php(9):
>   getData() #1 {main} thrown in
>   /www1/fe5/www.seansdesigns.co.uk/web/foodApp/test.php on line 33

If I call both functions individually it works so the sql is working OK.

```
<?php

$test = "update";

if ($test == "update"){
    insertWeight();
    getData();
}

function insertWeight(){
    require_once "connect.php";

    $username = 'sean14';
    $weight = '60';
    $date = '20-01-03';

    $sql = "INSERT INTO $username (date, weight) VALUES (:date, :weight)";
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindParam(":weight", $weight);
    $stmt->bindParam(":date", $date);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt = null;
}

function getData(){
    require_once "connect.php";

    $username = 'sean14';

    $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM $username");
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt = null;
    $x = 0;
    while ($row = $stmt->fetch()){
        $x++;
        $items[$x] = $row;
    }
    echo json_encode ($items);
}
?>
```

Comment: Inside getData you are defining $stmt as null, then trying to call the fetch() function on it.

Comment: $pdo is defined in the connection.php file which is included. I have also moved the $stmt to bottom of the function and still same. Seeing as both functions will work independently this should not be the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$pdo` appears to be undefined in both your functions. What is the contents of "connect.php"? I'm guessing it's defined there.

But since you told PHP to only require it **once** it will only get included into the `insertWeight` function. When you request to include it again in `getData` it won't be, because it's already been included earlier. (And that also explains why there's no problem when you only call one of the functions at a time.)

So either change it to just `require`, or, better still IMO, require it once at the start of your script, and change that file so there's a function you can call (from within your other functions) which will return a connection object.

e.g.

```
require_once "connect.php";

function insertWeight(){
  $pdo = getPDOConnection(); //getPDOConnection will be a function defined in connect.php which returns a ready-made connection object.
  //...etc
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is that in the second function `require_once()` will see that you've already included the database connect code in the first function, but `$pdo` will be out of scope as it's declared inside that first function. Put the db connect in the main code body, and pass `$pdo` into each function it is needed in.

Comment: Brilliant thank you, I was putting the required_once outside but was getting a connection error. Did not realise I had to pass this variable $pdo into each function

Comment: @Steve8428 variables inside and outside of functions are separate. I suggest you read https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php